# how to put .flutter-plugins-dependencies in the gitignore?

Tags: git, flutter

i would like to ignore  .flutter-plugins-dependencies file when i run  a git push command, i have tried to remove the file from cache through this command
 `git rm -r --cached`

but it doesn't work. also i tried to indicate it in .gitignore file:

[image]

the .flutter-plugins-dependencies file always appears in my commits. i don't know what i should do

Comment: Had you already committed it before you added it to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Side note: consider copy-pasting your code examples instead of uploading screenshots of code. This way it will be easier for us to make edits to it or copy it and try ourselves. Also, text is way better than pictures from accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 32):

`git rm --cached .flutter-plugins-dependencies`

should solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

First add `.flutter-plugins-dependencies` to `.gitignore` file, then follow these steps

```
git rm -r --cached .        #untrack files
git add .                   #re-adding the files
git commit -m "issue fixed" #commiting changes
git push                    #pushing changes
```

Refer: [Why is .gitignore not ignoring my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936726/9774005)